# Does a set still satisfy the Archimedean property if it is bounded outside of itself?

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

For instance, if we take the set $M = \{f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n\}$ and assume that if $f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n$ with $0 < a_n$ then $0 < f(x)$ for large x, then this set is obviously bounded above by something like $h(x) = x^{n+1}$.

Knowing this, can this set still satisfy the Archimedean property if it isn't bounded by anything inside of $M$?

Comment: How is $M$ a set?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said $M = \{f(x) = a_0 + a_1x + \cdots + a_nx^n | a_i \in Z\}$

Comment: Can you specify what order relation you are using? Also you can artificially make any set bounded outside of itself.

Comment: The notation is still non standard. But I may try to guess: the set of polynomial functions of degree at most $n$ with integer coefficients? I second Keen's question: what is the order relation here?

Comment: $0 \prec f$ if $0 < f(x)$ for $x$ large enough. $f \prec g$ if $0 \prec g - f$. Your guess is correct, as well. What would be the standard notation for this? This is the notation that my real analysis professor has always used.

Comment: @BarbaricGlass Ah, yes. You had a LaTeX typo. To display `{...}` write `\{...\}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you defined it, your group can only have Archimedean property if $n=0$. If $n>0$, just take $1$ and $x$. Then for every natural number $m$, $m\cdot 1<x$, since eventually $x$ will be bigger than any natural number.

Comment: Thanks! When you say "take $1$ and $x$," what do you mean by that exactly? Do you mean to say that for $n > 0$, since there is an $x$ term, there will never be a natural number that can bound the set at large $x$ values?

Comment: @BarbaricGlass When $n>0$, $1$ and $x$ are both elements of $M$. The Archimedean property is that the statement $\exists a,b>0 \forall m \in \mathbb{N}, m\cdot a<b$  cannot be true, which is precisely the case when you take $a=1$ and $b=x$.